# Handle FutureWarning by converting pandas dataframe table to latex with function to_latex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, latex

I have some sourcecode to dynamically generate tables from python with some headline and write it into some latex file. It looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_tables():
    with open('tables.tex', 'w') as f:
        # header

        f.write("% !TeX TS-program = lualatex\n") 
        f.write("\\documentclass{article}\n")
        f.write("\\usepackage{booktabs}\n")
        f.write("\\usepackage{unicode-math}\n")
        f.write("\\begin{document}\n")

        fooder = "\\end{document}\n"

        for i in range(10):
            df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 5)))
            latex_table = df.to_latex(index=False,header=False,escape=False)
            f.write(f"Table {i}:")
            f.write("\n\\\\\n")
            f.write(latex_table)
            f.write("\\\\[2\\baselineskip]\n")

        f.write(fooder)

generate_tables()
```

Is it possible to prevent the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: In future versions `DataFrame.to_latex` is expected to utilise the base implementation of `Styler.to_latex` for formatting and rendering. The arguments signature may therefore change. It is recommended instead to use `DataFrame.style.to_latex` which also contains additional functionality.
  latex_table = df.to_latex(index=False,header=False,escape=False)
```

without loosing the parameters `index=False,header=False,escape=False`. In `df.style.to_latex` the paramter which can set are very different from `df.to_latex`

Answer (score 1):

Found some solution

Replace

```
latex_table = df.to_latex(index=False,header=False,escape=False)
```

by

```
latex_table = tbl_cpy.style.hide(axis='index').hide(axis='columns').to_latex()
```

`escape=False` does not necessarily need to be replaced cause the escape symbols like `$` are automatically imported.

Comment: that is the correct solution. `df.style.format(escpape="latex")` or even `df.style.format_index(escape="latex")` are also possible, and even setting the pandas styler options to escape LaTeX by default if you want that.